# Sort Criteria for Upcoming Event (list) for multi day/recurring event

Tags: datetime

I want to show a list of upcoming events in ascending order.
I have selected the following for my Sort Criteria for the "Upcoming" view

Content: Date - start date (asc)
Content: Effective Date - end date:value2 (asc)

However, I want to push a multi day event or recurring event to the top of the list if the event is occurring on the current date if the start date has passed.